# Key typed event not working for the first key typed. java

Tags: java, regex, swing, keylistener, jtextcomponent

The following is code block, where i have been trying to validate *jFormatedTextFeild*. When a key is typed (any key) code block does seem to execute for the first key typed. But works fine for second key typed ! Please help me :(

```
private void jFormattedTextField_ByingPriceKeyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {  
    System.out.println("key typed action ");
    String checking = jFormattedTextField_ByingPrice.getText();
    Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("[A-Z,a-z,&%$#@!()*^]");
    Matcher match = ptrn.matcher(checking);
    if(match.find()){
       txtPriceMessage.setVisible(true); 
       //text field which contains the message does not appears 
       //for first key typed only it appears when second key is typed.                 
    } else { 
        txtPriceMessage.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code especially with the KeyListener bits.

Comment: IIRC the key typed event happens before the text in the field actually changes. That would explain the behavior you are seeing. (You could find this out by simply printing the text during the event.)

Comment: and what would be the solution @radiodef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) to filter the values going to a text component in real time, that's what it's design for.  Take a look at [these examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter), there's even a `PatternFilter` for using with regular expressions...

For post validation, use a [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)